# Know the values ​of a field related to each other in a postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table made like this

```
|id     |name     |  parent_id|
|1      |Giovanni |          1|
|2      |Giovanni |          2|
|3      |Michele  |          2|
|4      |Francesca|          3|
|5      |Antonio  |          3|
|6      |Michele  |          3|
|7      |Angela   |          4|
|8      |Francesca|          4|
|9      |Anna     |          5|
```

I would need that once the first name is selected eg. "Giovanni"
it should find me all "Giovanni" and based on parent_id value find all linked names. At this point iterate by finding all the other names connected with those found in precedence, eg.

```
|1      |Giovanni |          1|
|2      |Giovanni |          2|
|3      |Michele  |          2|<--new parent_id
|6      |Michele  |          3|
|4      |Francesca|          3|<--new parent_id
|5      |Antonio  |          3|<--new parent_id
|8      |Francesca|          4|
|7      |Angela   |          4|
```

I figured I should protect recursive queries but I can't find a correct query

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, name, parent_id from mytable where name = 'Giovanni'
    union all
    select t.id, t.name, t.parent_id
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.parent_id = c.id and t.id <> c.id
)
select * from cte
```

The anchor of the recursive query selects all rows whose `name` is Giovanni, and then all related children.

It might be useful to keep track of the path to each node, so you can order the results:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, name, parent_id, array[id] path from mytable where name = 'Giovanni'
    union all
    select t.id, t.name, t.parent_id, c.path || t.id
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.parent_id = c.id and t.id <> c.id
)
select * from cte order by path
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried that query but I get the following result: |1      |Giovanni |          1|    |2      |Giovanni |          2|

Comment: @Wemapp: that would be suprising. I tested the queries and fixed a few glitches, though. Here is a db fiddle for your reference: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=882462e3f121a02da1bb77f15389e665

Answer (score 0):

Sorry @GMB you are absolutely right. I tried a table with slightly different values.
Values ​​are like that

```
|id     |name     |  parent_id|
|1      |Rossi    |         13|
|2      |Paolo    |         13|
|3      |Giovanni |         15|
|4      |Giovanni |         16|
|5      |Rossi    |         16|
|6      |Mario    |         17|
```

the result should be

```
|3      |Giovanni |         15|
|4      |Giovanni |         16|
|5      |Rossi    |         16|
|1      |Rossi    |         13|
|2      |Paolo    |         13|
```

thank you very much for your help